# Coldfusion: Setting up a second website on CF8 Enterprise

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Windows 2008 Server R2 64bit, ColdFusion8 Enterprise Edition (multi-server configuration), Plesk

Recently purchased dedicated hosting on Hostgator and set up a website with help from a server guy. I'm doing a second site on my own this time. I've successfully created the new site in plesk, pointed the domain etc, but now need to set up a new instance of ColdFusion for this new site and I'm not sure how to go about it. From my googling, I'm guessing it's simply a case of setting up a new "instance", which can be done via the coldfusion administrator. Is this correct? Is there anything else I need to know? Any gotchas waiting to bite me?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't *need* to set up a new CF instance for a new website: there's not a one-to-one relationship between the two ideas.

The minimum you really need to do is to set up the new website, in a directory within the CF application root, or within a CF-mapped directory if the dir is outside that root, and then run the web server connector (wsconfig.exe) to configure the website to pass requests for CF files to CF.

On a standard install, wsconfig.exe is located in the [coldfusion]/runtine/bin dir, and on a multiserver install it's in [JRun]/bin.

If you do add a new instance, you still need to run wsconfig to connect the website to the CF instance.

Comment: Thanks, I really wanted to make the most of my enterprise version. So, I thought they was a more preferable way than simply to put the website in the same root directory.

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely.  I was saying you don't *need* to, but you certainly can.  Like I said in my last para, if you do add a new instance, just run the wsconfig tool to connect the website to the new instance.

Comment: When creating a new instance in CFAdmin, what is the path I enter in "Server Directory" field?

Comment: Not to be obtuse, but it's the dir that you want to be the base dir for the CF instance ;-)  EG: if you want an instance "foo", the dir might be C:\JRun4\servers\foo.  This, btw, is probably a new question, not an adjunct to this existing one.  But no worries.

Dunno if you're read these docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSAB4367BA-6D91-4c69-8DBA-E2839394658A.html

Answer (score 0):

user460114, new instance == new "server", so when first instance crashes for some reason, second will still run because it uses separate heap space and lives it's own life.
You could use this for some other purpose like failover instance, or cluster, or staging instance. It's not needed in your case.

You need to need to make new directory in webroot, here's example:

**C:\inetpub\www\old_site**

**C:\inetpub\www\new_site**

And set new_domain.com to point to ..\new_site, and leave old_site.com point to ..\old_site.

Cheers